# Text inside textform field is padded up

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am observing that the text for the below form field somehow padded up. Also the cursor has become very small like a dot. Any ideas ?

I want the text field height same as the right side round button

[image]

```
  final border = OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.transparent,
  ),
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
    const Radius.circular(
      10.0,
    ),
  ),
);

return TextFormField(
  controller: controller,
  onChanged: onChanged,
  validator: validator,
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
  cursorColor: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
    color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    height: 0.1,
  ),
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
    filled: true,
    enabledBorder: border,
    focusedBorder: border,
    border: border,
    labelText: labelText,

    // remove label while in focus
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
    labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
      color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
      fontSize: 15,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: try to align with `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for for the additional padding and the small cursor is the font `height` which you are setting to `0.1` (keep the default `1.0` if you don't want the additional padding).

You can fix the cursor issue by setting `cursorHeight` to match your original font size

Note: use `cursorHeight` only if you want to keep the height as `0.1`